# Find the url of the GitHub page

Tags: docker, nginx, github-pages, bitnami

I'm taking over [a website](https://www.10studio.tech) by [Docusaurus V2](https://v2.docusaurus.io/docs/deployment/#deploying-to-github-pages), but I could not reach the previous developer anymore.

I know that the content of the website is deployed to GitHub Pages. I want to know **the real GitHub page url** that our website redirects to, does anyone know how to know that?

I have access to our server, and the domain name records (where I don't see the url of GitHub page). Apparently the previous developer used docker, here is `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3"
services:
  docusaurus:
    image: bitnami/nginx:1.16
    restart: always
    volumes:
    - ./build:/app
    - ./certs:/certs:ro
    - ./my_server_block.conf:/opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/server_blocks/my_server_block.conf:ro
    ports:
    - "3001:3001"
    - "3002:3002"
```

I could not find the path of `nginx.conf` in our server. Does anyone know where it may be?

**Edit 1:** here is `my_server_block.conf`:

```
server {
  listen  3002;
  absolute_redirect off;
  root  /app;

  location = / {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ https://$http_host/docs/introduction redirect;
  }

  location = /docs {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ https://$http_host/docs/introduction redirect;
  }

  location = /help {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ https://$http_host/docs/introduction redirect;
  }

  location = /addinHelp {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ https://$http_host/docs/introduction redirect;
  }

  location = /privacy {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ https://$http_host/privacy.html redirect;
  }

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }
}

server {
  listen  3001 ssl;

  ssl_certificate      /certs/server.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key  /certs/server.key;

  ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
  ssl_session_timeout  5m;

  ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3002;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl on;
  }
}
```

Comment: Does not look like you are redirecting to any GitHub Page but maybe you could check the siteConfig.js file. Should be in something like /build/website/siteConfig.js on the host: https://docusaurus.io/docs/en/publishing#using-github-pages

Comment: This web is built from [Docusaurus v2](https://v2.docusaurus.io/docs/deployment/#deploying-to-github-pages), the file is `docusaurus.config.js`. In the file, we have speccified `url: 'https://chengtie.github.io'`. However, launching `https://chengtie.github.io` returns 404 error. Is it normal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the documentation https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-nginx

I think `my_server_block.conf` is your configuration file.

You can `docker exec` into the container or you can go to the directory from where you ran the docker compose command and look for that file.

It is clearly mounted onto the container from the host `./my_server_block.conf:/opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/server_blocks/my_server_block.conf`

Comment: Thank you... But I have no knowledge about docker or bitnami. I don't want to ruin our server. Could you give me some harmless instructions to get the path of `my_server_block.conf` in our server?

Comment: `my_server_block.conf` should be present on your host server as it is mounted to the container, you can just do a `find` command for it?

Comment: I have found `my_server_block.conf` (see OP), but I cannot see the url of github page...

Comment: is it possible that nginx is not redirecting to github at all? it might be some other script?

Comment: This web is built from [Docusaurus v2](https://v2.docusaurus.io/docs/deployment/#deploying-to-github-pages), there is a file `docusaurus.config.js`. In the file, we have speccified `url: 'https://chengtie.github.io'`. However, launching `https://chengtie.github.io` returns 404 error. Is it normal?